# Matlab : How to represent a real number as binary

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, quantization

**Problem :** How do I use a continuous map - The [Link1: Bernoulli Shift Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_transformation) to model binary sequence?

**Concept :** 
The Dyadic map also called as the Bernoulli Shift map is expressed as `x(k+1) = 2x(k) mod 1`. In [Link2: Symbolic Dynamics](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~wj/LTCC/notes/notes04.pdf), explains that the Bernoulli Map is a continuous map and is used as the Shift Map. This is explained further below.

A numeric trajectory can be symbolized by partitioning into appropriate regions and assigning it with a symbol. A symbolic orbit is obtained by writing down the sequence of symbols corresponding to the successive partition elements visited by the point in its orbit. One can learn much about the dynamics of the system by studying its symbolic orbits. This link also says that the Bernoulli Shift Map is used to represent symbolic dynamics.

Question :

How is the Bernoulli Shift Map used to generate the binary sequence?  I tried like this, but this is not what the document in Link2 explains. So, I took the numeric output of the Map and converted to symbols by thresholding in the following way:

```
x = rand();
 y = mod(2* x,1)  % generate the next value after one iteration

y =

    0.3295 
if y >= 0.5 then s = 1
else s = 0
```

where `0.5` is the threshold value, called the critical value of the Bernoulli Map.

I need to represent the real number as fractions as explained here on Page 2 of Link2.

Can somebody please show how I can apply the Bernoulli Shift Map to generate symbolized trajectory (also called time series) ?

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

How do I convert a real valued numeric time series into symbolized i.e., how do I use the Bernoulli Map to model binary orbit /time series?

Comment: (I've rolled back a major edit on this question, as per all the others).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can certainly compute this in real number space, but you risk hitting precision problems (depending on starting point). If you're interested in studying orbits, you may prefer to work in a rational fraction representation. There are more efficient ways to do this, but the following code illustrates one way to compute a series derived from that map. You'll see the period-n definition on page 2 of your Link 2. You should be able to see from this code how you could easily work in real number space as an alternative (in that case, the matlab function `rat` will recover a rational approximation from your real number).

**[EDIT] Now with binary sequence made explicit!**

```
% start at some point on period-n orbit
period = 6;
num = 3;
den = 2^period-1;

% compute for this many steps of the sequence
num_steps = 20;

% for each step
for n = 1:num_steps

    % * 2
    num = num * 2;

    % mod 1
    if num >= den
        num = num - den;
    end

    % simplify rational fraction
    g = gcd(num, den);
    if g > 1
        num = num / g;
        den = den / g;
    end

    % recover 8-bit binary representation
    bits = 8;
    q = 2^bits;
    x = num / den * q;
    b = dec2bin(x, bits);

    % display
    fprintf('%4i / %4i  ==  0.%s\n', num, den, b);

end
```

Ach... for completeness, here's the real-valued version. Pure mathematicians should look away now.

```
% start at some point on period-n orbit
period = 6;
num = 3;
den = 2^period-1;

% use floating point approximation
x = num / den;

% compute for this many steps of the sequence
num_steps = 20;

% for each step
for n = 1:num_steps

    % apply map
    x = mod(x*2, 1);

    % display
    [num, den] = rat(x);
    fprintf('%i / %i\n', num, den);

end
```

And, for extra credit, why is this implementation fast but daft? (HINT: try setting num_steps to 50)...

```
% matlab vectorised version
period = 6;
num = 3;
den = 2^period-1;
x = zeros(1, num_steps);
x(1) = num / den;
y = filter(1, [1 -2], x);
[a, b] = rat(mod(y, 1));
disp([a' b']);
```

OK, this is supposed to be an answer, not a question, so let's answer my own questions...

It's fast because it uses Matlab's built-in (and highly optimised) `filter` function to handle the iteration (that is, in practice, the iteration is done in C rather than in M-script). It's always worth remembering `filter` in Matlab, I'm constantly surprised by how it can be turned to good use for applications that don't look like filtering problems. `filter` cannot do conditional processing, however, and does not support modulo arithmetic, so how do we get away with it? Simply because this map has the property that whole periods at the input map to whole periods at the output (because the map operation is multiply by an integer).

It's daft because it very quickly hits the aforementioned precision problems. Set `num_steps` to 50 and watch it start to get wrong answers. What's happening is the number inside the filter operation is getting to be so large (order 10^14) that the bit we actually care about (the fractional part) is no longer representable in the same double-precision variable.

This last bit is something of a diversion, which has more to do with computation than maths - stick to the first implementation if your interest lies in symbol sequences.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the code does not give binary representation of the fractions. moreover, I fail to find the difference between the first two versions of your code in terms of the result returned -- the numerator & denominator values are the same. Should they be same or am I missing something ? Could you please show how the fraction to binary representation since by Question was how to represent real numbers to binary floating? Thank you once again for the details.

Comment: Hi. The first two give the same answers, yes, they just compute the sequence in different spaces. You can recover the binary... I'll do an edit.

Comment: DEC2BIN converts non-negative decimal integers to a binary string. So, I was wondering if one of the value is - 2/21 then how is this converted to fractional binary (using two's complement) and say for 16 bit precision? Thank you for the other clarification

Comment: None of the values are negative, I'm not sure if that is a minus sign or a dash in your comment. 2/21 can be converted to binary as shown, by promoting by some scaling factor, rounding (done implicitly by dec2bin), and, well, converting to binary. A "fractional" binary representation is just a choice, by you, of where the implicit binary point is. My edit above puts it in front of the binary number (see fprintf statement) and displays 8 binary bits after the binary point. You can choose to display 16 if you need to.

Comment: Bravo for the great explanations efforts.

Comment: @RattusExMachina: In this case, there is no negative fractions but in general, for other dynamical systems there may be negative fractions. dec2bin does not explicitly handle signed decimals. So, can you also put that up?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's relevant to the original question. If you represent the value in 2's complement, say, the original property of the "bit shift" map is lost, I think. However, if you have a negative fractional x, and you want to produce its two's complement scaled to 16 binary fractional bits, I think `dec2bin(bitxor(uint16(-x*65536), uint16(65535))+1)` will get you there. There may be a neater way, of course ;).

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to deal with rational type of output, you'll first have to convert the starting term of your series into a rational number if it is not. You can do that with:

```
[N,D] = rat(x0) ;
```

Once you have a numerator `N` and a denominator `D`, it is very easy to calculate the series `x(k+1)=mod(2*x(k), 1)` , and you don't even need a loop.

for the part `2*x(k)`, it means all the `Numerator(k)` will be multiplied by successive power of 2, which can be done by matrix multiplication (or `bsxfun` for the lover of the function):
so `2*x(k)` => in Matlab `N.*(2.^(0:n-1))` (N is a scalar, the numerator of x0, `n` is the number of terms you want to calculate).

The `Mod1` operation is also easy to translate to rational number: `mod(x,1)=mod(Nx,Dx)/Dx` (`Nx` and `Dx` being the numerator and denominator of `x`.

If you do not need to simplify the denominator, you could get all the numerators of the series in one single line:

```
xn = mod( N.*(2.^(0:n-1).'),D) ;
```

but for visual comfort, it is sometimes better to simplify, so consider the following function:

```
function y = dyadic_rat(x0,n)

   [N,D] = rat(x0) ;                   %// get Numerator and Denominator of first element
   xn = mod( N.*(2.^(0:n-1).'),D) ;    %'// calculate all Numerators
   G = gcd( xn , D ) ;                 %// list all "Greatest common divisor"
   y = [xn./G D./G].' ;                %'// output simplified Numerators and Denominators
```

If I start with the example given in your wiki link (`x0=11/24`), I get:

```
>> y = dyadic_rat(11/24,8)
y =
    11    11     5     2     1     2     1     2
    24    12     6     3     3     3     3     3
```

If I start with the example given by *Rattus Ex Machina* (`x0=3/(2^6-1)`), I also get the same result:

```
>> y = dyadic_rat(3/63,8)
y =
     1     2     4     8    16    11     1     2
    21    21    21    21    21    21    21    21
```

Comment: The idea of a dyadic rat scares me a little. Sort of... Stephen King.

Comment: @RattusExMachina. Yes I know ... odd name for a function. I thought that too. I called it like that because it was just an extension of a `dyadic` function I gave him in a previous question, but this time with rational output ... so lack of imagination I just appended `rat` to the name. Finally the lack of imagination ... created a new monster !!